# Listview mostrar dos campos en cada fila

Tags: c#, wpf, listview

Visual Studio Community 2015 + SQLite + Entity Framework

La base de datos tiene 2 campos: ID y ShipType

Clase para mapeo de la base de datos:

```
namespace ImperialFleet
{
public class ShipTypeClass
{
    private string id;
    private string type;

    public ShipTypeClass(string id, string type)
    {
        this.Id = id;
        this.ShipType = type;
    }

    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string ShipType { get; set; }
}
}
```

Código para cargar el Listview

```
        private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        List<string> shipList = new List<string>();
        using (var db = new ImperialFleetDBEntities())
        {
            shipList = (from g in db.ShipsType select g.ShipType).ToList();

       }

        listView.Items.Clear();                   
        foreach (string str in shipList)
        {
            listView.Items.Add(str);
        }
```

xaml Listview

```
<ListView x:Name="listView" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="198" Margin="39,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="446">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn/>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
```

**Cómo puedo hacer para mostrar la otra columna con el campo ID?**

```
(from g in db.ShipsType select g.ID).ToList()
```

Comment: Muestra el xaml de tu ListView.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Intenta utilizando `GridViewColumn` especificandole la propiedad de la cual va mostrar en la propiedad `DisplayMemberBinding` en el XAML:

```
<ListView x:Name="listView" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="198" Margin="39,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="446">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
              <GridViewColumn Header="Id" Width="Auto" 
                            DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Id}"/>

            <GridViewColumn Header="Shit Type" Width="Auto" 
                            DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding ShipType}"/>    
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

Cada propiedad especificada en el DisplayMemberBinding representa la propiedad de tu modelo, asi que tienes que asegurar que tengan el mismo nombre.

Entonces para mostrar la data solo tendiras que asignar la coleccion a la propiedad `ItemsSource` del ListView:

```
List<string> shipList = new List<string>();
using (var db = new ImperialFleetDBEntities())
{
    listView.ItemsSourrce = db.ShipsType.ToList();
}
```

Comment: Funcionó perfecto. No sabía que había que modificar el XAML para agregar columnas. Gracias