# Eliminar de la base de datos el registro seleccionado en el Listvew (Usando Entity Framework)

Tags: c#, listview, orm

Siguiendo con el ejemplo de [Listview mostrar dos campos en cada fila](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/118201/listview-mostrar-dos-campos-en-cada-fila)

Visual Studio Community 2015 + SQLite + Entity Framework

La base de datos tiene 2 campos: ID y ShipType

Clase para mapeo de la base de datos:

```
namespace ImperialFleet
{
public class ShipTypeClass
{
    private string id;
    private string type;

    public ShipTypeClass(string id, string type)
    {
        this.Id = id;
        this.ShipType = type;
    }

    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string ShipType { get; set; }
}
}
```

Código para cargar el Listview

```
        private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        List<string> shipList = new List<string>();
        using (var db = new ImperialFleetDBEntities())
        {
            shipList = (from g in db.ShipsType select g.ShipType).ToList();

       }

        listView.Items.Clear();                   
        foreach (string str in shipList)
        {
            listView.Items.Add(str);
        }
```

xaml Listview

```
<ListView x:Name="listView" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="198" Margin="39,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="446">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Id" Width="Auto" 
                        DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Id}"/>

                <GridViewColumn Header="Tipo nave" Width="Auto" 
                        DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding ShipType}"/>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
```

**No se como tomar el Id (que es único en la base de datos) del registro seleccionado en el listview y luego eliminarlo de la base de datos, si es que tengo que generar una nueva instancia con el objeto a borrar o si solamente preciso referenciarlo por su ID de alguna forma**

Supongo que será algo del estilo

```
            using (var db = new ImperialFleetDBEntities())
        {

            db.ShipsType.Remove(IDdelItemABorrar);
            db.SaveChanges();
    }
```

pero no se como "tomar" IDdelItemABorrar desde el Listview

Comment: Agrega el metodo del evento que se lanza cuando se selecciona el `GridViewColumn`

Comment: No entiendo bien el pedido. La idea es que el usuario hace clic en una fila del Listview y luego hace clic en un botón ELIMINAR 
El evento que lanzaría la eliminación del registro estaría dentro de ese botón algo del tipo
` private void button2_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
        }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solución:

```
        private void button2_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        var ShipSelected = (ShipsType)listView.SelectedItems[0];
        using (var db = new ImperialFleetDBEntities())

        {
            db.ShipsType.Attach(ShipSelected);
            db.ShipsType.Remove(ShipSelected);
            db.SaveChanges();

            //Refrescar la lista de barcos
            listView.ItemsSource = db.ShipsType.ToList();
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Si estas utilizando un Modelo detrás de la View puedes utilizar la propiedad **SelectedItem**, para recuperar el elemento seleccionado, te recomiendo que utilices el patron [MVVM](https://fernandomachadopiriz.com/2010/06/09/una-simple-introduccin-al-patrn-model-view-viewmodel-para-construir-aplicaciones-silverlight-y-windows-presentation-foundation/) para que puedas hacer estas cosas mas fácil sin recargar el Code Behind. Saludos

```
    <ListView x:Name="listView" ItemsSource="{Binding ShipList}" SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectShip}">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Id" Width="Auto" 
                                DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Id}"/>

                <GridViewColumn Header="Tipo nave" Width="Auto" 
                                DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding ShipType}"/>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
```

Modelo/ViewModel/Code behind:

```
   private ObservableCollection<ShipTypeClass> _shipList;
    private ShipTypeClass _selectShip;

    public ObservableCollection<ShipTypeClass> ShipList
    {
        get { return _shipList; }
        set { _shipList = value; this.OnPropertyChanged(nameof(ShipList));}
    }

    public ShipTypeClass SelectShip
    {
        get { return _selectShip; }
        set { _selectShip = value; this.OnPropertyChanged(nameof(SelectShip)); }
    }

   private void CargarLista()
    {
        List<ShipTypeClass> listTmp = new List<ShipTypeClass>();
        using (var db = new ImperialFleetDBEntities())
        {

            listTmp = db.ShipsType;

        }

        ShipList.Clear();
        foreach (var str in listTmp)
        {
            ShipList.Add(str);
        }
    }
```

y dentro de un botón o cualquier rutina que tengas para confirmar que quieres eliminar solo tienes que hacer:

```
    public void EliminarRegistro()
    {
        var entity = this.GetById(SelectShip.Id);
```

// obtenemos el objeto, si quieres comprobar de que aun existe 
en base de datos puedes pasarle el ID; De lo contrario 
puedes pasarle directamente el selector SelectShip
 en lugar de entity.

```
        if (entity != null)
        {
            using (var db = new ImperialFleetDBEntities())
            {
                // eliminamos el registro
                db.ShipsType.Remove(entity);
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Agradezco toda la explicación pero no entiendo entonces la ventaja de usar ORM. En modo tradicional lo que podía hacer era tomar el ID de la fila seleccionada en el ListView y usando ese valor con un comando SQL borrar el registro en la base de datos. Yo pensaba que al tener un "emparejamiento" entre la base de datos y objetos alcanzaba con una orden del tipo db.ShipsType.Remove(ID); tomando el ID directamente del listview. Aclaro soy nuevo en esta tecnología, voy es intentar aplicar las soluciones aportadas.

Comment: Un ORM no te hace todo el trabajo, tampoco un ORM te va a hacer el trabajo de cosas con la IU, un ORM te va a mapear tus datos de la bdd a objetos en memoria, te facilita las funciones crud, y, en algunos casos como Entity Framework, te facilita las búsquedas usando linq. Es Tu responsabilidad como desarrollador el cómo utilizar esos datos, en este caso para mostrarlos al usuario. Aparte, para WPF deberías utilizar el patrón  MVVM, sobretodo si la aplicación es de mediana a grande.

Comment: De momento solo estoy aprendiendo pero toda la información que brindas me sirve y orienta en la dirección correcta. :)

Comment: Acabo de publicar la solución que encontré.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes asignarle la referencia del objeto a la propiedad `Tag` del GridView, bindiandolo con `Binding`:

```
    <!--Le asignamos el objeto a la propiedad Tag, -->
    <GridView Tag="{Binding Path=.}">

        <GridViewColumn Header="Id" Width="Auto" 
                DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Id}"/>

        <GridViewColumn Header="Tipo nave" Width="Auto" 
                DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding ShipType}"/>
    </GridView>
</ListView.View>
```

`Tag="{Binding Path=.}"` significa que `Tag` seria igual al objeto asignado en el `ItemsSource`, en este caso, `ShipType`.

Ahora en el delegado `listView_SelectionChanged` verificamos si el elemento seleccionado es un `GridView` y si lo es, casteamos el valor de la propiedad `Tag` al tipo que le asignados en el binding:

```
private void listView_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var item = listView.SelectedItem as GridView;

    if(item != null)
    {
        ShipType ship = item.Tag as ShipType; // obtenemos el objeto asignado al tag.

        using (var db = new ImperialFleetDBEntities())
        {
            // eliminamos el registro
            db.ShipsType.Remove(ship);
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Si agrego <GridView Tag="{Binding Path=.}"> me subraya indicando

The member "Tag" is not recognized or is not accesible